# Why can't I pass functions as arguments across classes in C++?

Tags: c++, function, class, parameters, parameter-passing

so I'm trying to pass a function as an argument across two classes of mine in C++:

```
void class1::func_1(QString str)
{
    class2* r = new class2();
    r->func_2(str, &process);
}

void class1::process(QString str)
{
     //Do something with str
}
```

Where 'r->func_2' looks like the following:

```
QString class2::func_2(QString str, void (*callback)(QString))
{
   //Do something else
}
```

Yet when I try to compile, I get the following errors:

```
must explicitly qualify name of member function when taking its address
    r->func_2(str, &process);
                    ^~~~~~~~
                     class1::

cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void (*)(QString)' with an rvalue of type 'void (class1::*)(QString)'
    r->func_2(str, &process);
                    ^~~~~~~~
```

And I can't figure out why. Any ideas? I'm clearly doing something wrong... just not sure what. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Function pointers and member function pointers are separate types. The latter needs an instance of the class.

Comment: Can you make these functions `static`? If you can, that should solve the problem. If you cannot, you need to look into `<functional>`, or use C++11's lambdas.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I would recommend the <functional> or lambdas if C++11 is usable, and if not, prefer boost's version of <functional> to static.

Answer (score 5):

You need to fully qualify the member function name when you pass its address:

```
void class1::func_1(QString str)
{
    class2* r = new class2();
    r->func_2(str, &class1::process);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The functions are member functions and they are not static. I suggest you to make use of std::function and std::bind. Through these you will be able to take functions as arguments. Just keep in mind that when you will be using std::bind to pass in the argument and it is not a static/global functions but a member of a some object, you need to also make use of this thing called placement. Look it up. You don't need to use lambdas by the way.

```
class A
{
    std::string m_name;
    void DisplayName() { std::cout << m_name };
}

void TakeFunctionAsArgument(std::function<void(void)> func)
{
    func();
}

int main()
{
    A objectA;
    TakeFunctionAsArgument(std::bind(&A::DisplayName, objectA));
    return 0;
}
```